# Dative of Personal Interest?

Tags: grammar-choice, grammar-identification, ovidius, metamorphoses, dative

In this line in Ovid Metamorphoses Book III. 505, is ***fratri*** put in the Dative because *' of the person **in whose honour,** or interest, or advantage or for whose pleasure, an action takes place, or the reverse (Dativus Commodi et Incommodi):*

> ... planxere sorores 
>   naides et sectos **fratri** posuere capillos,
>   planxerunt dryades;<

Translated as

*His naiad-sisters beat their breasts and shore their locks in sign of grief for their dear brother;* (F.J. Miller)

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that sounds correct. It could be argued that the dativus commodi is the most common use of the dative, and it can be translated in various ways. In this sentence, *in honour of their brother* is good.